# Users Randomly Being Redirected to the Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Having a problem that's incredibly hard to diagnose, so hoping to find some suggestions.

It's a Rails site using Devise/Cancan. Timeoutable is turned off. There are many Projects, and each one has several forms for child entities. Users login, view a specific project, and edit those forms.

These form pages are very basic CRUD. Nothing fancy in the view or controller.

Occasionally, the user will edit the form, submit it and, instead of going to the update action, they'll go to the root. I have a log of each page load plus the production log from Rails (at log level debug) showing this.

It doesn't hit update and get redirected. They're just on edit, then at the root. The only way for them to get there would be to click the logo in the top left.

It doesn't happen every time, so it's hard to reproduce. I've witnessed it happen several times over remote desktop or I would assume it was just some end user issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Tearing my hair out.

Comment: Do you detect cancan exceptions? If the user can't perform the given action, do you go to root?

Comment: cancan should just be exploding into the unauthorized page of doom. There are a number of Unauthorized redirects from Devise in the log, but the times don't match up, and since the entire site requires login, it's not really outo f place.

I'm going to disable it today to see if that makes a difference though.

On phoets... thread safety could definitely be part of this. Going to investigate that too.

Thanks dudes, I'll post more info when I have it.